# ssis importing two excel files with different number of columns into database

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2010, csv, ssis

I want to build a ssis package that imports a flat file with variable number of columns and stores it in a database table. further i will be using that table to left join with few other tables to find if a particular column value matches with the ones i already have in the database. Then i want to give all non matching rows as output in another folder as a csv file.

So how to write a for each loop to import variable column number flat file and store it in a table. Can we write a package to create a table after it imports a file or can we store the imported file in a temp table created dynamically, because it doesnt matter if the table is deleted after the package stops.

thanks

Comment: Yes you can create a table after you execute your for each loop.  Use an `Execute SQL Task` to create your temp table and write your procedure..I would actually recommend writhing a stored procedure and then calling the stored procedure in the `Execute SQL Task`...Just pass your DTS variables to the stored procedure...reference this to learn to pass your variables :  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933470(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: If you want to use dynamic columns you will have to use a script task/component. The data sources are can't handle dynamic columns.