# SSIS Excel export data dynamically

Tags: ssis

I have a to load data through SSIS into Excel, But source data has coumn headers will be changing dynamically. Can anyone help me on this.

Source is View

Data will be like this

column -1   column-2  column -3
20160504   20160511   20160518

Next time data will come like this

column-1  column -2 column -3
20160511   20160518 20160522

Comment: Show us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489552/ssis-importing-two-excel-files-with-different-number-of-columns-into-database

Answer (score 0):

Specify in your xls connection manager that the file has no headers. Then in you xls data source, specify a sql command like:

```
select F1,F2,F3 from [sheet1$:A2:C]
```

In this case it will select the 3 first columns, starting at row 2 (so you skipped your header).